# Can't install SweetAlert2 in Laravel 6.0

Tags: sweetalert2, laravel-6

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for realrashid/sweet-alert ^2.0 -> satisfiable by realrashid/sweet-alert[v2.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
- realrashid/sweet-alert v2.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.4.0|~5.8.0|~5.9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev].

- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0].
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.0.0, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.0].
```

Comment: I think laravel 6 support is still on it's way on this library keep checking github repo for all packages updates here : https://github.com/realrashid/sweet-alert/issues/46

Answer (score 0):

The `realrashid/sweet-alert` package has not been updated for use in Laravel 6.0. You will have to wait until it is updated, update the package yourself, or use a different package for SweetAlert2.

Update: The package has been updated for use with Laravel 6.0.

```
composer require realrashid/sweet-alert
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much.. . . Huhuhuhu I can't install it.. :(

Comment: Hi. How can I update the package myself? Not just sweetalert2 but other packages are still not updated to use for Laravel 6.0.